# Angular Tutorial - Where did I get lost?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I'm following the Angular tutorial on Thinkster located [here](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/). I got to the part where you refractor the posts into a service, and all of a sudden my app is broken. Here's my code (app.js):

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', []);

app.factory('posts', [function(){
  var o = {
    posts: [];
  };
  return o;
}]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope', 'posts',
function($scope,posts){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
  $scope.posts = posts.posts;
  $scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
    $scope.posts.push({
        title: $scope.title,
        upvotes: 0,
        link: $scope.link
    });
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
  }
  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(which){
    which.upvotes += 1;
  }
}]);
```

and the HTML (index.html):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> First Angular App </title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script> <!-- Angular app -->
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Title"
            ng-model="title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Link"
          ng-model="link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried plenty of different stuff, moving around posts that I had, etc. (the code listed above doesn't have my posts in it; i took them out)
Where is my bug?

If it helps at all, here is how the code looks in my browser: [image](http://i1167.photobucket.com/albums/q634/michael_ward7/Screenshot%20from%202015-04-19%20153717_zps15dkyjrj.png)

Comment: Any errors in the console window?

Comment: Haven't even ran with node or anything else yet. Simply navigating to the page in my browser @Cerad.

Comment: $scope.posts = posts.posts;

try
$scope.posts = posts()

Comment: The browser console window.  Press F12.  You might be amazed.

Comment: I'm getting a "missing } after property list" at line 5 in app.js (posts: [])

Comment: haha... haha.. haha... @Cerad, my error was adding a semicolon to posts: []; it's supposed to be posts: [] \n }.
Fixed, guys :)

Comment: It surprises me this tutorial still uses `$scope` instead of the recommended `controller as` syntax (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, remove **;** from `posts: [];`

```js
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', []);

app.factory('posts', [
  function() {
    var o = {
      posts: []
    };
    return o;
  }
]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts',
  function($scope, posts) {
    $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    $scope.addPost = function() {
      if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
        return;
      }
      $scope.posts.push({
        title: $scope.title,
        upvotes: 0,
        link: $scope.link
      });
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.link = '';
    }
    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(which) {
      which.upvotes += 1;
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
      {{post.upvotes}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
      </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Add a new post</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='addPost()'>Post</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```